# Postgres query on partitioned table 2x slower than non-partitioned table

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance, database-partitioning, postgresql-9.6

We have a table with 4 million records and we created partitions for that table, assuming the select queries will be faster on partition-enabled tables. However, the select on partition-enabled tables are 2x slow!!

1. On normal table (**24 ms**)
   `explain analyse select * from tbl_original where device_info_id = 5;`
2. On partition-enabled table (**49 ms**)
   `explain analyse select * from tbl_partitioned where device_info_id = 5;`

Following is the output of the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` command for `tbl_original`:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_original  (cost=61.19..9515.02 rows=2679 width=379) (actual time=0.297..13.008 rows=3369 loops=1)     
  Recheck Cond: (device_info_id = 5)                                                                                          
  Heap Blocks: exact=554                                                                                                      
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_tbl_original  (cost=0.00..60.52 rows=2679 width=0) (actual time=0.232..0.232 rows=3369 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (device_info_id = 5)                                                                                      
Planning time: 0.087 ms                                                                                                       
Execution time: 24.890 ms
```

Following is the output of the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` command for `tbl_partitioned`

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Append  (cost=0.00..6251.14 rows=3697 width=404) (actual time=0.034..36.635 rows=3369 loops=1)                                                             
  ->  Seq Scan on tbl_partitioned  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=1069) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)                                           
        Filter: (device_info_id = 5)                                                                                                                       
  ->  Index Scan using idx_tbl_partitioned_p1 on tbl_partitioned_p1  (cost=0.42..6251.14 rows=3696 width=404) (actual time=0.017..12.922 rows=3369 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (device_info_id = 5)                                                                                                                   
Planning time: 0.184 ms                                                                                                                                    
Execution time: 49.129 ms
```

Looks like the most expensive operation in the partitioned query is *Index Scan* taking **6251.14** units. However, considering the size of the partition table as compared to the original table this Index Scan should have been very fast. Not sure if we are missing anything obvious here!

Any help in optimizing the query/partitioned table will be appreciated.

Note: The partitioned table was created using the following:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_partitioned (LIKE tbl_original);

CREATE TABLE tbl_partitioned_p1 (
    CONSTRAINT pk_tbl_partitioned_p1 PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT ck_tbl_partitioned_p1 CHECK ( device_info_id < 10 )
) INHERITS (tbl_partitioned);

CREATE INDEX idx_tbl_partitioned_p1 ON tbl_partitioned_p1 (device_info_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_tbl_partitioned ON tbl_partitioned (device_info_id);

INSERT INTO tbl_partitioned_p1 SELECT * from tbl_original where device_info_id < 10;
```

The sizes of the tables are :

```
select count(*) from tbl_partitioned; -- 413696 rows
select count(*) from tbl_original;    -- 4417025 rows

select count(*) from tbl_original where device_info_id = 5; -- 3369 rows
```

`constraint_exclusion` is set to `partition`

Comment: What is your Postgres version (`select version()` will tell you). Can you also please add the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, buffers)` (especially for the partitioned case)

Comment: ``PostgreSQL 9.6.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, 64-bit``

Comment: But in general for just 4 million rows I wouldn't bother introducing partioning.It's not a "make every thing go faster" magic bullet.

Comment: This table will grow over time. This is a snapshot with few weeks worth of data. For eg, there is a ``device_info_id`` for which the original table takes ~8secs:

``explain analyse select * from tbl_original where device_info_id = 72; -- Execution time: 8780.177 ms``

Comment: In that case you should seriously consider upgrading to Postgres 11. Partitioning support was massively improved since 9.6 (especially partition pruning and parallel execution)

Comment: That increase comes from append operation. Even if you add CHECK on parent table so that it isn't included in search it will still perform append. I think that only way to get rid of it is to query partition directly, for example using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting more EXPLAIN DATA like:

> explain (ANALYZE, TIMING, COSTS, BUFFERS, VERBOSE) select * from
>   tbl_original where device_info_id = 5;

In particular, pay attention to the "hits" in the ouptut like:

> Buffers: shared hit=4 read=224

Read=xxx means that a block had to be read from disk. Hit= means that it came from RAM (shared buffers). It's possible that more of your data is in shared buffers -- performance is very dependent on that.